# Angular reactive form is visible from localhost but not visible when deployed to prod

Tags: angular

Prod: throwing Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance

Local: works fine

Could not replicate the issue from local.

Tried anything I could think of, out of idea.

The page has containerComponent and have 5 childComponent.
The form is instantiated from containerComponent and passed to childComponents.
Each childComponents displayed via Tab and ngIf.

Needed a way to keep the state of object and save once but require to display in sections

Comment: Any error ? You need to provide more info if you want everyone help you

Comment: Wish I could provide more, all I am getting is this message from prod 'Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance'

Comment: Upload your code please

Comment: Where are you instantiating your form? The class constructor or the OnInit lifecycle hook or what?

Comment: We have a class called AbstractFormComponent and it has initializeMultiForm() method. and The component I am working on extends AbstractFormComponent  and calls initializeMultiForm() in OnInit. The form is instantiated in initializeMultiForm() using formBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prod build needs you have initialized your form with a FormGroup intance. Then my recomendation is use the constructor or the ngonInit to initialize your form and if you need to reasignate the form with new values you can do it different functions.

```
ngOninit(){
   InitializeForm();
}

InitializeForm(){
   this.sampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [null],
      name: [null]
    });
}

resetValues(){
  ...
  InitializeForm();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, finally got it working, it was all because of Class name property. We are using multiforms by having many groups and used class name as group name. when we were building form, the group name was set with Class.Name(to extract the name of the class). it was working fine from local but on prod the group names appears to be '1' so we changed it to string and it works fine